# How can I get my DisplayLink monitor running (again) - 15.10, Asus MB168B+

Tags: multiple-monitors, asus, displaylink

I have been installing Ubuntu on a laptop (Samsung QX410-SO2), and while there have been hurdles, my Asus DisplayLink monitor is one of the things that worked immediately after driver install.

I first set it up yesterday, and it was working well and behaving as expected. After resuming from sleep later in the day, the monitor was blank. I needed to be portable so I wasn't worried about it - disconnected and walked away.

Now, I can't get the monitor to be recognized at all. I am very new to Ubuntu, but I would really like to get this working again.

To get it working originally, I downloaded displaylink-driver-1.0.335.run  from displaylink.com. After that I plugged the monitor in and after a short delay it just worked.

I am seeing the monitor recognized in dmesg output :

```
[    2.090374] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=ff03
[    2.090380] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.090384] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: MB168B+
[    2.090386] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[    2.090389] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: DALMTF138452
[    2.808469] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    7.078269] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.254436] systemd[1]: Failed to insert module 'kdbus': Function not implemented
```

Though the last outputs from dmesg don't look good :

```
[    9.646516] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.646696] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[    9.646711] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[    9.697280] [ ] evdi_init Initialising logging on level 5
[    9.820542] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[    9.823280] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823391] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823457] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823522] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823587] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823652] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823764] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.823830] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[    9.890237] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   10.548062] i2400m_usb 2-1.3:1.0: WiMAX interface wmx0 (64:d4:da:1c:31:40) ready
[   10.666277] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   12.989696] wlp2s0: authenticate with 60:a4:4c:69:a8:50
[   12.995823] wlp2s0: send auth to 60:a4:4c:69:a8:50 (try 1/3)
[   12.997655] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   12.997848] wlp2s0: waiting for beacon from 60:a4:4c:69:a8:50
[   13.013135] wlp2s0: associate with 60:a4:4c:69:a8:50 (try 1/3)
[   13.019591] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 60:a4:4c:69:a8:50 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   13.023237] wlp2s0: associated
[   13.023288] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   14.012644] i2400m_usb 2-1.3:1.0: untested minor fw version 9.3.2
[   14.012652] i2400m_usb 2-1.3:1.0: firmware interface version 9.3.2
[   14.020531] usbcore: registered new interface driver i2400m_usb
[   14.022466] i2400m_usb 2-1.3:1.0 enx64d4da1c3140: renamed from wmx0
[   16.425187] [D] add_store  increasing device count to 1
[   16.425524] [D] evdi_crtc_init drm_crtc_init: 0
[   16.425529] [D] evdi_encoder_init drm_encoder_init: 0
[   16.425630] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[   16.425637] evdi evdi.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
[   16.425641] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[   16.427967] evdi evdi.0: fb1: evdidrmfb frame buffer device
[   16.427978] [drm] evdi: evdi_stats_init
[   16.427990] [drm] Initialized evdi 1.0.68 19700101 on minor 2
[   16.428865] [W] evdi_painter_disconnect (dev=0) An unknown connection to ffff88003555c400 tries to close us - ignoring
[   16.429307] [W] evdi_painter_disconnect (dev=0) An unknown connection to ffff88003555c400 tries to close us - ignoring
[   16.473118] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[   16.473163] [D] evdi_detect Painter is disconnected
[   16.473619] [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify (dev=0) Notifying crtc state: 0
[   16.473625] [D] evdi_painter_crtc_state_notify (dev=0) Notifying crtc state: 0
[   18.661534] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   22.851144] [W] evdi_painter_disconnect (dev=0) An unknown connection to ffff8800c5260c00 tries to close us - ignoring
[   22.863078] [D] evdi_painter_connect (dev=2) Connected with ffff8800c5260c00
[   22.863086] [D] evdi_painter_connect (dev=2) Edid (3 bytes): 00 ff ff
[   22.863091] [D] evdi_detect (dev=2) Painter is connected
[   22.865501] [D] evdi_detect (dev=2) Painter is connected
[   22.865511] [D] evdi_painter_get_edid (dev=2) 00 ff ff
```

Is there an obvious clue here that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This laptop has two graphics cards - an Intel built-in, and NVidia discrete card. I switched to the intel card (using nvidia prime), rebooted, and my display is back.

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

I am posting this in case it can help anyone in the future, but if anyone knows how to keep the Asus Monitor running while still using the NVidia card that would be the preferred solution.

Comment: I keep reading through different channels that DisplayLink does not work at all with the Intel's 3d libGL library. I actually installed Ubuntu and Arch both with working Bumblee/Prime profiles and in both cases the DisplayLink failed to work. This time I am installing Ubuntu with only the Nvidia stuff to see if I get a different result.